# How to understand assumption from stability theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

Consider $$x'(t)=A\cdot x(t)+f(t,x(t)),\,\,x(0)=a$$
for $t\geq0$. Assume that $A$ is real $N\times N$ matrix with negative real parts of eigenvalues, $f\colon \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^N\to\mathbb{R}^N$ is continuous and locally Lipschitz with respect to the second argument. Moreover, assume that $f(t,0)=0$ for all $t\geq 0$ and 
$$\frac{\|f(t,x)\|}{\|x\|}\to 0$$
uniformly as $x\to 0$ for all $t\geq 0$. Then, $x=0$ is asymptotically stable. How shall I understand the last hypothesis? Is it
$$\forall \varepsilon>0\, \exists\,\delta>0\,\forall\, x\in\mathbb{R}^N\, \forall t\geq0\, \|x\|<\delta\implies \frac{\|f(t,x)\|}{\|x\|}<\varepsilon$$
or 
$$\forall \varepsilon>0\, \exists\,\delta>0\,\forall\,  t\geq0\,\forall x(t)\in\mathbb{R}^N\, \|x(t)\|<\delta\implies \frac{\|f(t,x(t))\|}{\|x(t)\|}<\varepsilon\,\,?$$

Also, does it follow from the hypothesis that if $\|x(0)\|$ is sufficiently small, then for all $t\geq 0$ we have that $\frac{\|f(t,x(t))\|}{\|x(t)\|}<\varepsilon$? -$\delta$ is chosen independently from time.

**Edit.**
Suppose for now, that $t\in [0,T]$. Let $x(\cdot)$ be a solution of our problem.  We know that 
$$x(t)=ae^{At}+\int_{0}^{t}e^{(t-s)A}f(s,x(s))\,ds$$ and we can estimate the last term to get
$$\|x(t)\|\le \|a\| c_1e^{-c_2t}+\int_{0}^{t}c_1e^{-c_2(t-s)}\|f(s,x(s))\|\,ds.$$
In order to use Gronwall's lemma we need to estimate $\|f(s,x(s))\|$. It follows from 
$$\forall \varepsilon>0\, \exists\,\delta>0\,\forall\, x\in\mathbb{R}^N\, \forall t\geq0\, \|x\|<\delta\implies \frac{\|f(t,x)\|}{\|x\|}<\varepsilon$$ that
$$\forall \varepsilon>0\, \exists\,\delta>0\,\forall\, x\in\mathbb{R}^N\, \forall t\geq0\, \|x\|<\delta\implies \|f(t,x)\|<\varepsilon \|x\|.$$
In order to use the last estimate in our situation we need to assume however that 
for all $t\in [0,T]$, $\|x(t)\|< \delta$ which is an absurd. So in my opinion we are not allowed to use Gronwall lemma in here, at least directly. Another problem is, that Gronwall's lemma is valid if $t\in [0,T]$ (at least this version I can prove), so what happens if $t\in [0,\infty)$? I believe we can use Gronwall's lemma in the way I wanted, but first we have to introduce a Lyapunov funcion $L(x)=Q(x,x)$, where
$$Q(x,y)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\langle e^{\xi A}x, e^{\xi A}y\rangle_{\mathbb{R}^N}\,d\xi$$
and secondly prove that if $x(0)\in M=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^N\,|\, L(x)\le r\}$, then $x(t)\in M$ for all $t\ge 0$. Then the assumption of $\|x(t)\|<\delta$ will be justified for $t\ge 0$ and applying Gronwall's lemma will get asymptotic stability.

Comment: It is the first variant, it is a property of the function $f$, not of any prospective solutions. You have interpreted "uniformly in $t$" correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your help. So, if I understand you correctly, we cannot deduce that if $\|x(0)\|<\delta$, then $\frac{\|f(t,x(t))\|}{\|x(t)\|}<\varepsilon $.

Comment: No, not from this assumption alone. You will need to use the contracting properties of the ODE. Essentially the assumptions say that for $x(0)$ close enough to $0$ the ODE is a small perturbation of $\dot x=Ax$ which is contracting by the assumptions, and you can use perturbation arguments such as the Grönwall lemma to make this an exact statement.

Comment: I've edited my post, so you can see now, that using Gronwall's lemma will not allow us to deduce $\|x(0)\|<\delta \implies \frac{\|f(t,x(t))}{\|x(t)\|}<\varepsilon$, I guess.